# Can the width of a mosfet modify the gate-source voltage?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, analog

I was solving a problem divided in two parts. 
The first is a simple calculation, but the second implies reasoning, and it's here where the post question arise.

The first part importance for the second is just the following data:

$$
I_D = 1\ mA \\
\mu_nC_{ox} = 100\ \mu A/V^2 \\
V_{TH} = 0.5\ V \\
\lambda = 0
$$

With next schematic:

[image: schematic]

Where 10/0.18 is the ratio W/L. 
And MOSFET is working in saturation region, so far that's all.

The second part says:
Suppose we double \$W\$ and choose \$R_D\$ to place \$M_1\$ at the edge of saturation. Is the resulting gain higher or lower than the above value?

I solved that question in both numerical and analytical ways, and they give me ***gain increases***. 
But the issue comes when I'm thinking around the analytical expressions: if I'm variying the \$W\$ with \$I_D\$ fixed, that implies \$V_{GS}-V_{TH}\$ is changing, so the question would be, **is \$W\$ overwriting the \$V_{GS}\$ bias circuitry? or is this a too ideal case, that doesn't happen in real designs?**

This was my solution:

[image: Equations]

Thanks!

---

Edition inspired by Elliot Alderson comment:

Assuming that changing \$W\$ forces the change of \$I_D\$ and not \$V_{GS}\$ (which makes much more sense), when doing the analysis, the gain voltage \$A_v\$ actually experiences no change:

[image: Root Analysis]

But, If we continue the analysis, now with the fraction, where \$R_D\$ forces to change the \$V_{DS}\$ we see that the reduction of the subtrahend increases the gain voltage:

[image: Fraction Analysis]

Again, is this right?

Comment: Why do you assume that \$I_D\$ is fixed when \$W\$ is changed?

Comment: Because the second part of the problem proposes to vary only \$W\$ and \$R_D\$. But I was thinking about your question and maybe \$V_{GS}-V_{TH}\$ remains constant so \$I_D\$ change (increases) to compensate variations of \$W\$, If this happens, let me add something and please give me your feedback.